# UWP: Store file on network USB drive

Tags: c#, networking, uwp, raspberry-pi3

I want my raspberry Pi 3 (Windows IoT) to store a txt file.
The Pi3 is connected to my home LAN network which is operated by my netgear router (manual http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/WNDR3700V5/WNDR3700v5_UM_03Sept2015.pdf).
The router also supports to connect a USB drive (called "Ready Share") to store data.

My goal is to let my UWP app running at the Pi3 store the txt at a dedicated folder on the USB drive.

Unfortunately, this is not working:

```
Windows.Storage.StorageFile sampleFile =
await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("\\ReadyShare\MyNewFolder\MyTxt.txt",
    Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

I get an error saying that the path is not existing.

Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons you are not allowed to access arbitrary folders. You must first let the user give you permission to do so; this can be done by letting the user point to the folder he wants you application to use (with a `FilePicker` or similar). The user must do this once, afterwards your application gains permanent access to those files/folders.

See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions